# Ошибка "The type or namespace name ... could not be found"

Tags: c#

Я не программист, но по работе приходится сталкиваться с `С#`. Возникла проблема с ним - напишите пожалуйста, как исправить ошибку.

Ничего не меняется от добавления библиотеки. Пишу код и формулировку ошибки, не удивляйтесь, если она (ошибка) будет элементарная

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

using DevExpress.Xpo;
using DevExpress.Data.Filtering;

using DevExpress.ExpressApp;
using DevExpress.Persistent.Base;
using DevExpress.Persistent.BaseImpl;
using DevExpress.Persistent.Validation;
using DevExpress.ExpressApp.Model;
using ModelDefaultAttribute;

[DefaultClassOptions]
[ModelDefault("Caption", "Task")]
public class DemoTask : Task
{
    public DemoTask(Session session) : base(session) { }
    [Association("Contact-DemoTask", typeof(Contact))]
    public XPCollection Contacts
    {
        get { return GetCollection("Contacts"); }
    }
}
```

Ошибка

> Error 1   The type or namespace name
> 'ModelDefaultAttribute' could not be
> found (are you missing a using
> directive or an assembly
> reference?)   C:\Users\shilin\documents\visual
> studio
> 2010\Projects\Solution8\Solution8.Module\DomainObject4.cs 12  7   Solution8.Module
> Error 2   The type or namespace name
> 'ModelDefaultAttribute' could not be
> found (are you missing a using
> directive or an assembly
> reference?)   C:\Users\shilin\documents\visual
> studio
> 2010\Projects\Solution8\Solution8.Module\DomainObject4.cs 16  2   Solution8.Module
> Error 3   The type or namespace name
> 'ModelDefault' could not be found (are
> you missing a using directive or an
> assembly
> reference?)   C:\Users\shilin\documents\visual
> studio
> 2010\Projects\Solution8\Solution8.Module\DomainObject4.cs 16  2   Solution8.Module

Объясните пожалуйста, что не так, а то меня точно уволят

Comment: Хм. Попробуйте указать в начале файла

    using DevExpress.ExpressApp.Model;

Если не выйдет, спросите лучше у программиста. Примените кодовую фразу "В каком неймспейсе и какой сборке лежит `ModelDefaultAttribute`"?

Comment: @Stepan Shilin, не нужно создавать одинаковые вопросы. Лучше дополните ваш вопрос комментарием или отредактируйте его.

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте в солюшн библиотеку ModelDefaultAttribute. (References - Add)

В файле DomainObject4.cs допишите

```
using ModelDefaultAttribute;
```

Comment: в References солюшн не нахожу ModelDefaultAttribute, где он лежит?